# Rotate Polygon to be Parallel with the X Axis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

By default, PostGIS calculates the Envelope or Extent of a polygon based on the bounding box of the polygon `((MINX, MINY), (MINX, MAXY), (MAXX, MAXY), (MAXX, MINY), (MINX, MINY))`.

This gives a result like so:

[image]

However, I'm looking for a result more like this:

[image]

As far as I know, the best algorithm that I can come up with is:

1. Determine angle `a` to rotate the polygon `X` to be parallel with the x-axis
2. Rotate `X` `a` degrees, calculate the envelope `Y` of rotated polygon `X`
3. Rotate `Y` `-a` degrees

How could you calculate step #1 in PostGIS?

Comment: Too bad there's no [ST_MinimumRectangle](http://www.h2gis.org/docs/dev/ST_MinimumRectangle/) function for PostGIS, see [enhancement ticket #3176](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3176)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation.  It doesn't handle degenerate cases and you
may not like the rectangle chose if the areas tie.  I'm working on
a submission for postgis, but this should be enough to work with until
I get a patch into postgis.

```
create or replace function ST_MinimumRectangle(g geometry) returns geometry
language 'plpgsql' as $$
declare
        hull geometry;
begin
        hull = ST_ExteriorRing(ST_ConvexHull(g));
        -- one side must lie along the rectangle.
        -- so, for each side, rotate, bbox, counter-rotate bbox
        with sides as (
                select ST_PointN(hull, n) as a, ST_PointN(hull, n+1) as b,
                        n as side
                        from generate_series(1,ST_NPoints(hull)-1) n
                ),
        angles as (
                select side, a, b, st_azimuth(a, b) as angle from sides
        ),
        boxes as (
                select ST_Rotate(ST_Envelope(ST_Rotate(hull, -angle)),angle) as rect, side, angle from angles
        )
        select rect into hull from boxes order by ST_Area(rect), side limit 1
        ;
        return hull;
end;
$$ immutable strict;
```

Answer (score 0):

***Small fix.***

Somehow it worked for me as:

```
select ST_Rotate(ST_Envelope(ST_Rotate(hull, **angle**)),**-angle**)
```